# JS: I am trying to understand event emitters vs event listeners

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the difference between event handlers and event emitters.
I understand event *listeners* and how to attach them, for example, the following:

```
let element = document.getElementById('test-id');

element.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
})

function handleClick() {
    console.log("is this function considered an event handler?")
}
```

But even after reading about event emitters and handlers, I don't know exactly how or where they come into play.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the emit() method whenever you need, passing the name of the event and any number of arguments. For example:

```
const EventEmitter = require( 'events' );
class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
    doSomething() {
        // do something...
        if ( !err )
            this.emit( 'success', result );
        else
            this.emit( 'error', err );
    }
}
```

You can find the full API documentation of the EventEmitter class [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/events.html).

Refer here also [What is an "event emitter"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438924/what-is-an-event-emitter)

Answer (score 0):

**event emitters** - code that create event - you write code to create events and then you write handlers for it.

**event listeners** - event is created by browser eg - http request, click- you write code to handle the events that is listeners.