# jQuery $.on.apply not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

Any one know why

```
$.on.apply(this, args);
```

gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

I know for sure that $.on is defined in jQuery :/

Comment: what are you trying to achieve??

Comment: I'm trying to bind events on a custom object

Comment: apply of undefined shows $ is undefined.

Comment: Giyf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796788/whats-the-apply-jquery-function

Answer (score 3):

The `on()` method is bound to `$.fn` `$`

```
$.fn.on.apply(this, args);
```

Comment: now I get Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: what is the jQuery version

Comment: it's the latest. it works if I use it with html element

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is incorrect.
use syntax like

```
$('el').on("click", function() {
       alert( $( this ).text() );
       });
```

Comment: instead of `$(this).text`, you could just write `this.textContent`, though. It saves you a number of function calls

Answer (score 1):

You know for sure `$.on` is defined, well... I beg to differ:

```
console.log($.on);//undefined
console.log($.fn.on);//function (a,c,d,e,f)
console.log($().on);//function...
```

Not sure though, that what you're trying to do is a valid use-case for jQuery's `on`, besides, applying the `on` function to a custom object doesn't give that object magical properties... I mean: it's not like that object will all of a sudden become clickable, if it's just an object literal

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to make use of jQuery's event system in my own app. ppl say that you can use events on custom objects: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/triggering-custom-events-on-js-objects#14737000000743154

Comment: found the info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553342/custom-event-in-jquery-that-isnt-bound-to-a-dom-element. It seems to work if I call on() normally, but if I use apply I get that weird error :/

Comment: @Elfy: jQuery doesn't actually have its own event system, it merely hatches on to JS's event loop, and provides a consistent API for it. You can register _"fake"_ events, though, and manually invoke the handler: `jQObject.trigger('myevent');`, but that still means you have to _manually_ trigger the event, and rather defeats the point, imo